# How do you use WebFlux to parse an event stream that does not conform to Server Sent Events?

Tags: spring, docker, spring-webflux

I am trying to use WebClient to deal with the Docker `/events` endpoint.  However, it does not conform to the `text/eventstream` contract in that each message is separated by **2** LFs.  It just sends it as one JSON document followed by another.

It also sets the MIME type to `application/json` rather than `text/eventstream`.

What I am thinking of but not implemented yet is to create a node proxy that will add the required line feed and put that in between but I was hoping to avoid that kind of workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to handle a `ServerSentEvent`, just receive it as a `String`.  Then attempt to parse it as JSON (ignoring the ones that fail which I am presuming may happen but I haven't hit it myself)

```
@PostConstruct
public void setUpStreamer() {
    final Map<String, List<String>> filters = new HashMap<>();
    filters.put("type", Collections.singletonList("service"));

    WebClient.create(daemonEndpoint)
        .get()
        .uri("/events?filters={filters}",
           mapper.writeValueAsString(filters))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(String.class)
        .flatMap(Mono::justOrEmpty)
        .map(s -> {
            try {
                return mapper.readValue(s, Map.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.warn("unable to parse {} as JSON", s);
                return null;
            }
        })
        .flatMap(Mono::justOrEmpty)
        .subscribe(
            event -> {
                log.trace("event={}", event);
                refreshRoutes();
            },
            throwable -> log.error("Error on event stream: {}", throwable.getMessage(), throwable),
            () -> log.warn("event stream completed")
        );
}
```